# route aspx to controller

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, routes

I try to redirect an old page version in aspx into my controller with route system.

Sample:

```
old Urlpage : ~/mypage.aspx?extraparam=123
new UrlPage : ~/HomeMyaction?extraparam=123 (or /Home/MyAction/123)
```

I try this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "MyPage",
                url: "mypage.aspx",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "MyAction" },
                namespaces: new string[] { "MyApp.Controllers" });


routes.MapRoute(
                name: "MyPage",
                url: "{namepage}.aspx",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "MyAction" },
                namespaces: new string[] { "MyApp.Controllers" });
```

But every try my site return an error 404 because he try to access to "mypage.aspx" but they doesn't exist anymore and I can't change my old access.

I try to ignore "mypage.aspx" like .axd

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("mypage.aspx/{*pathInfo}");
```

But I've Always 404 BadRequest 'Ressources not found'

Answer (score 0):

After close VisualStudio and ReBuild my entire solution, my route works fine.

I don't know why...

i use this :

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "MyPage",
            url: "mypage.aspx",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "MyAction" },
            namespaces: new string[] { "MyApp.Controllers" });
```